# replace missing value by grouping with mean

Tags: r, mean

I have a table with countries and gdp and missing value. I want to replace with a mean but not the whole colomn mean just which include in the same group
I have 27 countries and 11 years. like

```
countries year GDP
1         2001   125
1         2002    ...
1         2003   525
2         2001   222 
2         2002  ...
```

So I would like to get the mean of the first country all year and replace with missing value for GDP

I know how to replace the whole colomn

```
data$gdp[which(is.na(data$gdp))]<- mean(data$gdp, na.rm=TRUE)
```

but this will calculate the whole colomn. Dont want to take a subset of each country and calculate seperatly I was thinking if I could do it in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using `na.aggregate` (from `zoo` - by default it takes the mean and replace the `NA` elements) grouped by 'countries'

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(countries) %>% 
    mutate(GDP = na.aggregate(GDP))
```

Comment: @Sonny  You may need to use `replace` or `case_when` within `mutate`

Comment: yes, i was thinking of `GDP = ifelse(is.na(GDP), mean(GDP, na.rm = T), GDP)`. Anyways, na.aggregate is better shorthand